# AlertDialog do not show positive and negative button

Tags: android, dialog

I used AlertDialog to alert user confirm delete. I check on my device (Android 5.1) and it show well

[image]

But on some another device (also run Android 5.1), the dialog missed positive and negative button.

[image]

I checked and found that devices happen this issue have a medium resolution (960x540, 854x480).

Is resolution relate with this issue ?
If not, can you tell me the reason and how to fix this issue ?

My code for display dialog:

```
    public static final Dialog yesNoDialog(Context context,
                                               String message,
                                               DialogInterface.OnClickListener yesAction, DialogInterface.OnClickListener noAction) {


            AlertDialog.Builder  builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.todoDialogLight);

            builder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", yesAction)
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", noAction);
            return builder.create();
 }
```

**And styles.xml**

```
  <style name="todoDialogLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

            <!-- Used for the buttons -->
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <!-- Used for the title and text -->
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorText</item>
            <!-- Used for the background -->
            <!-- <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>-->
            <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
            <item      name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/RemindDialogAnimation</item>
            <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/width_remind_dialog</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 59):

So the buttons are there for me.  Unfortunately, they were white text on white background. It has nothing to do with the resolution but more to do with the theme you are choosing. To solve this you need to set the right text color in your dialog theme.

For example, in styles.xml add

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBlue</item>
</style>
```

and in your activity add

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer works but it doesn't work with the new design library. Check my answer for a more updated solution.

Answer (score 15):

*@Ali answer is correct but doesn't work with the new Design Library*

To use it with the design library, use this style.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then you use it like this.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
                    .setMessage("The message")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ -> /* Do something*/}
                    .setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ -> }
                    .show()
```

Answer (score 4):

We can set the color to the buttons.

```
public  void showImageDownloadDailog(Activity activity, String message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                   //TODO
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //TODO
              }
            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> {
        alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color));
        alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color));
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: //Adding these two lines solved my issue.
alert.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> {
        alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color));
        alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color));
    });

Answer (score 3):

Ali's solution worked for me.  My original code worked on previous android versions <7.  But testing on my Pixel gave invisible buttons.  I added the style concept detailed by Ali as shown below and all is well:

```
   return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.MyDialogTheme)
            .setView(v)
            .setTitle(R.string.filter_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    // when the user presses the button to select a new number
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Integer markerIndex = mNumberPicker.getValue();
                            stringFilter=uniqueValues[markerIndex];
                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,  stringFilter);
                        }
                    })
            .create();
```

Answer (score 3):

this problem can also happen if you call :

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
```

after the call to :

```
dialogBuilder.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but maybe someone else need it, change your style to this one MyAlertDialogStyle:

```xml
 <style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- Used for the title and text -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <!-- Used for the background -->
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/MyPositiveTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/MyNegativeTextStyle</item>

 </style>
 <style name="MyTitleTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFEB3B</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title</item>
 </style>
 <style name="MyPositiveTextStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button</item>
 </style>
 <style name="MyNegativeTextStyle"  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really relate to resolution, I do not know exact the reason and just make a if else condition to fix this issue.

```
public static String getDensity(Context context) {
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if (density >= 4.0) {
            return "xxxhdpi";
        }
        if (density >= 3.0) {
            return "xxhdpi";
        }
        if (density >= 2.0) {
            return "xhdpi";
        }
        if (density >= 1.5) {
            return "hdpi";
        }
        if (density >= 1.0) {
            return "mdpi";
        }
        return "ldpi";
}
```

**AlertDialog**

```
    public static Dialog yesNoDialog(final Context context,
                                               final String message,
                                               final DialogInterface.OnClickListener yesAction,
                                               final DialogInterface.OnClickListener noAction) {
            int theme = PreferenceUtil.getThemeSetting(context, PreferenceUtil.PREF_THEME);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;
            String density = AppUtil.getDensity(context);
            if (theme == ThemeUtil.THEME_LIGHT) {
                if(density.equals("hdpi")){
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                }else{
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.todoDialogLight);
                }
            } else {
                if(density.equals("hdpi")){
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                }else{
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.todoDialogDark);
                }
            }
            builder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", yesAction)
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", noAction);
            return builder.create();
   }
```

Hope it help for others developer who have the same problem.

Comment: What is all this? where is PreferenceUtil? where are the styles "todoDialogLight" and "todoDialogDark"? please improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom theme in your `styles.xml` set the color of `colorAccent` to a darker color.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `colors.xml` and change your `colorAccent` from this:

```xml
<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
```

to this:

```xml
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog dialog;

```
public void startAlertDialog(String message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialoglayout,null);
    TextViewRagular textViewRagular=(TextViewRagular)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewMessage);
    textViewRagular.setText(message);
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    dialog=alertDialog.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

You can replace MainActivity.this by your activity, using getAplicationContext() will cause your app crashing because it asking for activity instead of context

> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
> AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
> View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_profile_icon, null);
> builder.setView(view);
> ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
> imageView.setImageURI(imagePath);
> builder.setMessage("Your Message");
> builder.setCancelable(false);
> builder.setPositiveButton(
> "Yes",
> new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
> public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
> //TODO
> }
> });
>
> ```
>     builder.setNegativeButton(
>             "No",
>             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
>                     dialog.cancel();
>                 }
>             });
>
>     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
>     alert.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> {
>         alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
>         alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
>     });
>     alert.show();
> ```