# AlertDialog not showing positive and negative button in Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have displayed `AlertDialog` with 2 buttons i.e. Yes and Cancel, here is the code.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RiderDetailActivity.this);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

This doesn't show yes and cancel button only on samsung galaxy s4

[image]

But when i use it with with `dialog.setButton` it works perfectly

```
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

[image]

**Note :** `builder.setPositiveButton` and `builder.setNegativeButton` is creating problem on just Samsung Galaxy S4, for other devices it is working perfectly.

#### UPDATE

I need to create dialog after setting buttons to builder, but my concern is why it was working with other devices and just creating problem with Samsung Galaxy S4?

Comment: `final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`    add this line above `dialog.show();`   and see

Comment: @Redman yes that works, but why it was working with other devices and emulators earlier? If this is my mistake, it should not work with other devices also.

Comment: that is expected behavior since you add buttons to a builder after you've build a dialog. Move your `final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`after you add button

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes i got that, but in that case it should not work with other devices and emulators also.

Comment: it *may not work*. There are a lot of undocumented features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog do not show positive and negative button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481735/dialog-do-not-show-positive-and-negative-button)

Answer (score 5):

Try this way. I hope this will work for you.

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: yes that works, but why it was working with other devices and emulators earlier?

Comment: Sometimes Samsung OS create some problem with android.Please vote for answer

Comment: wow nice explanation, can you tell me what is samsung os?  i thought it was android

Comment: I know Samsung also bases on android OS. But rumors a I have listened that Samsung also modify something when it install android in its devices.Because sometime i also get problem only in samsung while code is working fine in other devices

Answer (score 5):

After your `alertDialog.show()` method add these two lines

```
alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.red));
alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.red));
```

Comment: Does it mean earlier button was there but having transparent textcolor?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but in some of device it is not showing.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating your Dialog before adding the buttons.

Just move

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

after setting your buttons

Comment: yes that works, but why it was working with other devices and emulators earlier?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya as you know that Samsung customizes android's original version at too much level that's why Samsung creates the problem.
Xiomi Redmi is also same as Samsung, maybe if you'll test with that device, you can get those issues too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code..

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Add new Title")
                .setMessage("Type Message here")
                .setPositiveButton("Add", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                   // Onclick event Here
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Close",(dialog, i) -> {

                })
                .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I get that error after call Builder.create(); before positive and negative button. So I do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_statistic, null);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setCancelable(false);

// Initialize view
...

builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        // Do something
        builder.create().dismiss();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

// This for edit color and caps text
TextView ok = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
TextView no = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
ok.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_200));
ok.setAllCaps(false);
no.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_200));
no.setAllCaps(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example me, I didn't have my button showing on AlertDialog when was setting message to empty String ("").