# displaying AlertDialog inside tab view activity consisting of fragments

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display `AlertDialog` inside tab views activity consisting of fragments . 
this is my java code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.dis:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); //Read Update
            alertDialog.setTitle("Support us to improve");
            alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.w4);
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

now i can display the dialog box , but the onclick listener was not working for `setPositiveButton()` , the button was not displaying in the dialog box.

this is my output now , how do i add an button here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Positive button before showing dialog .

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
        alertDialog.setTitle("Support us to improve");
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.w4);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Do your stuff
            }
        });
       alertDialog.show();
```

Also you do not need to call `dialogInterface.dismiss();` it will automatically dismiss . Its `AlertDialog's` property for default buttons.

Comment: I tried what you just told me ,still the output was same ,the button was not displaying

Comment: Are you sure you used the code above and called `show()` only once . Cause it should work .

Comment: yeah , that's exactly what i did , i think the problem was due to onclick listener - this code was working fine for activity , but now i am using it in tab view activity with fragments inside that , the dialog box was actually displaying there but sadly without buttons in it

Comment: This does not make any sense . `AlertDialog` depends on Context only . Try to clean and rebuild the project and reinstall the apk. Also check if button text color is not white . It can be possible the button are there with same text color as background color. [Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481735/dialog-do-not-show-positive-and-negative-button).

Comment: Still the output is same ,

I am using "rate" icon at the action bar to open this dialog box which is from menu in resources ,which is in Main activity and by default my activity will display fragment_one  , does this have anything to do with this problem ?

Comment: the text color and the background are same i changed it everything works fine now thanks man - his solved my problem.