# Android Webview Alert Dialog Button White colour

Tags: android, button, colors, android-webview, android-alertdialog

[image]

Hi all.

Do we have any way to change the alert dialog button in webview? At the moment the alert dialog button is white and it can't be seen as the background colour is white as well.

Tried changing the webview user agent and also tried to override onJsAlert, but it does not help. I tried to debug but it does not go into onJsAlert function when the alert dialog is shown.

```
    mContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle).
                        setTitle("YourAlertTitle").
                        setMessage(message).
                        setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }
```

Tried accessing the website on mobile web browser and the button colour is black. Just in Android app is white colour.

Any advice on changing the alert dialog button colour?

Comment: You can create custom alert dialog with your own view - check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53550564/8041528

Comment: @PankazKumar Hi. The alert dialog is from the webview. Try to customize from onJsAlert but can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AlertDialog do not show positive and negative button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481735/alertdialog-do-not-show-positive-and-negative-button)

Comment: @aryanknp Hi. When I try to debug it does not goes into onJsAlert function. So unable to set the theme for the webview alert dialog box.

Comment: @MeiYi is `mContentWebView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: @aryanknp Have added this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved as the prompt was onJsConfirm.

```
            @Override
            public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityBrowserWithoutToolbar.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(url);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                        getString(R.string.ok_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                        getString(R.string.cancel_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                result.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> {
                    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
                    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Alert Dialog uses the activity theme, so the positive button color uses the colorAccent of the activity theme defaultly. you should check it.

if you did not set the activity theme, please check the colorAccent of your application theme.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).